# How to make transparent elements render elements behind them in WebGL?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I have a 3-D mesh composed of cubes in WebGL. Each cube is made of triangle primitives. Some of the cubes need to be transparent, allowing cubes in the background to show through.

My current solution allows for transparent cubes but renders the canvas background--the clear color (I think)--instead of the cubes behind. The attached picture shows the issue which is somewhere in my mess of WebGL code. Let me know if you have any ideas.

[Mesh image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khUkD.png)

```
function draw() {

        let colorData = [];

        // Loops through all cubes making each colored or transparent
        for (let i = 0; i < (N + extra) * N**2; i++){
            colorData = flu.dyeIdx(i, colorData);
        }

        // routine to output xyz coordinates from buffer into vertex shader
        const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer); // bind to current array buffer
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(meshVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW); // load vertex data into buffer and choose draw mode

        const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `
        precision mediump float;

        attribute vec4 position;
        attribute vec4 color;
        varying vec4 vColor;

        uniform mat4 matrix;

        void main() {
            vColor = color;
            gl_Position = matrix * position;
        }
        `);
        gl.compileShader(vertexShader)


        //routine to assign color shader
        const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer); // bind to current array buffer
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colorData), gl.STATIC_DRAW); // load color data into buffer and choose draw mode

        const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec4 vColor;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vColor;
        }
        `);
        gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);


        
        // "link" vertex and color shaders
        const program = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(program);

        // assign position, color, and uniform locations
        const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position'); // attribute index
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        const colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'color'); // attribute index
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


        //TRANSPARENCY
        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
        gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //DRAW OPAQUE OBJECTS HERE

        gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        //DRAW SEMI-TRANSPARENT OBJECTS HERE
        //gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, N, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);


        const uniformLocation = {
            matrix : gl.getUniformLocation(program, `matrix`)
        };

        gl.useProgram(program);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);



        let matrix = mat4.create();


        // change to 0, 0, 2.5 for redone origin
        mat4.translate(matrix, matrix, [0, .75, -4]);

        let projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
        mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix,
            50 * Math.PI / 180,   // vertical fov
            canvas.width / canvas.height, // aspect ratio
            1e-4,   // near cull distance
            1e4 // far cull distance
        );

        let outMatrix = mat4.create();
        
        mat4.rotateX(matrix, matrix, Math.PI/5);
        //mat4.rotateX(matrix, matrix, Math.PI/200);
        // comment for redone origin
        mat4.rotateY(matrix, matrix, Math.PI);
        //mat4.rotateZ(matrix, matrix, Math.PI/200);

        mat4.multiply(outMatrix, projectionMatrix, matrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocation.matrix, false, outMatrix);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, meshVertices.length / 3); // triangle, first vertex, draw all three
        // divide length of vertices array by 3 to get the number of vertices. vertices = coordinateComponents/componentsPerCoordinate(x,y,z)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of gl.drawArrays() was not there. I was able to sort my transparent and opaque elements and use them to draw each independently.

I drew it using this code:

```
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
        gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //DRAW OPAQUE OBJECTS HERE
        //console.log(opaque_indicies)
        //console.log(meshVertices.length/3)
        for (let i = 0; i < opaque_indicies.length; i++) {
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, opaque_indicies[i] * 36, 36); // triangle, first vertex, draw all three
            // divide length of vertices array by 3 to get the number of vertices. vertices = coordinateComponents/componentsPerCoordinate(x,y,z)
            //console.log(opaque_indicies[i] * 36)
        };


        
        gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        //DRAW SEMI-TRANSPARENT OBJECTS HERE
        for (let i = 0; i < transparent_indicies.length; i++) {
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, transparent_indicies[i] * 36, 36); // triangle, first vertex, draw all three
            // divide length of vertices array by 3 to get the number of vertices. vertices = coordinateComponents/componentsPerCoordinate(x,y,z)
        };
```